# Determinant of complex matrix from real and complex parts

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, determinant

Is is possible to find the absolute value of the determinant of a complex matrix M, given two real matrices A & B of the same dimension of M; where for N = 2,

M would be:  $\begin{matrix} a_{00} + i*b_{00} & a_{01} + i*b_{01} \\ a_{10} + i*b_{10} & a_{11} + i*b_{11} \end{matrix}$?

I.e. using just the real numbers and determinants of A & B is there any known relation that can get me the absolute value of the complex determinant from M? Thanks!

Comment: Please use mathjax/Latex syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ can be any matrix, really. Your question is somehow equivalent to; *is there a shorter formula for $\det (A+B)$ where $A, B \in \mathcal{M_n}(\mathbb{R})$* ?

Since the determinant application is *only* a group homomorphism from the [general linear group of degree $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) to $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$, meaning $\det(AB) = (\det A)( \det B)$ and $\det(A^{-1}) = (\det A)^{-1}$, **there is no general formula for the determinant of the sum of two matrices**.